# how am I screwing up counting the properties in this object?

Tags: php, object, count

I'm using domdocument() to retrieve data from a web page, and I want to count the number of matches:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($output);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$brands = $xpath->query('//li[@class="cp_item"]/a/p[1]'); // get the contents of the first paragraph inside the link
```

My (likely wrong) understanding is that $brands is an object of which the matches are properties. From PHP.net comments I get the following as a way to count the number of properties in the object.

```
$count_brands = count((array) $brands);
```

This yields 0 even though I can then see there are many matches using

```
foreach ($brands as $brand) {
    echo(trim($tag->nodeValue))
}
```

Obviously I'm either misunderstanding how the data is getting stored or misapplying the count() method. I'm just learning OO PHP so it's probably something stupid.

Comment: All you're doing is casting with `(array)`. You would need to `count()` the result of the cast with the parentheses, `count((array)$brands);`.

Comment: Demo: http://codepad.org/gMq01cCQ

Comment: @Jared Farrish sorry, `$count_brands = ((array) $brands);` was mistyped in my question, as I used `$count_brands = count((array) $brands);` in my actual code. The former yields a value of 'Array' whereas the latter yields the value I received, 0. I have since corrected the question (answered by Dr.Molle below). I appreciate your having taken the time to make the demo, especially given how I screwed up what I was asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "object" is  a [DOMNodelist](http://de3.php.net/domnodelist) and has a property **length** which contains the number of items.

```
$count_brands = $brands -> length;
```